# Sum of the digits of two numbers

Tags: number-theory

How do I proof that the sum of the digits of these two numbers:

$10^n-T$ and $10^{n+1}-T$
where n and T are positive integers, are not at the same time odd or even, i.e. if one of the sums is odd then the other is even and vice versa.

Comment: Consider $n=1$ and $T=33$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming both expressions and $T$ are positive) $$(10^{n+1}-T)- (10^n-T) = 9\times 10^n,$$ i.e. they have the same digits  except that the larger one has an extra $9$.

So the sums of their digits differ by $9$.

$9$ is odd.